# Parsing String to get an array of time stamps associated to words

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filereader

I have a string with the subtitle text below. Lets say I had an array of the words **[first, line, two]** , I want to get an array of the time stamps associated to when those words first appear like the following **[00:00:01.000, 00:00:15.000, 00:00:15:00]**.

I was wondering how to do this, What I thought I could do is when the word appears, try to find the most recent instance of " -->" and then just get the last 12 characters which would be the time stamp. I am just not 100% sure how to approach doing this via JS. I assume its using an index for position?

```
WEBVTT

1
00:00:01.000 --> 00:00:10.000
This is the first line of text, displaying from 1-10 seconds

2
00:00:15.000 --> 00:00:20.000
And the second line of text
separated over two lines
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe start with the split function:

```
var str = "00:00:01.000 --> 00:00:10.000";
var res = str.split(" --> ");
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res + "<br />";
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += res[0] + "<br />";
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += res[1];

// result:
// 00:00:01.000,00:00:10.000
// 00:00:01.000
// 00:00:10.000
```